# Как можно добавить два пака иконок IcoMoon на сайт?

Tags: html, css, icon

Привет

Зашел на проект, где уже подключены иконки шрифтами, а мне нужно добавить еще парочку. Как это можно сделать, ведь уже идет инициализация?

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
    font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
```

Пробовал добавить в font-family еще одно семейство - все упало. Что делать?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

выбери import to set
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И загрузи нужную иконку в формате svg

а потом с генерируй новый фонт

вот и все